# How can I eliminate Sensu notifications related to Passenger when actually the Nginx service is not running?

Tags: notifications, passenger, sensu

I have two Sensu Checks in place, one regarding Nginx and the other one regarding Passenger. First of one makes sure that Nginx service is running and the second one checks if Passenger processes are running.

```
    "nginx": {
    "command": "check-process.rb -p nginx",
    "handler": "mailer",
    "interval": 10,
    "occurences": 3,
    "refresh": 600,
    "standalone": true
},
"passenger": {
    "command": "check-process.rb -p \"Passenger RubyApp\"",
    "handler": "mailer",
    "interval": 10,
    "occurences": 3,
    "refresh": 600,
    "standalone": true
},
```

The problem is that when Nginx is down, automatically I am getting alerts that Passenger is down, which is normal judging by the current configuration. I want to eliminate Passenger notifications when the Nginx is down, cause I think are redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enterprise version of Sensu has this feature and its it called `check_dependencies`. If a check has an event and one or more of its dependencies has an event then it will not alert.

https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/enterprise/filters/check-dependencies.html

In your case you make `nginx` a dependency of `passenger`. Then, if the nginx goes down the passenger alert would not fire.